# Django doesn't insert rows into table with multiprocessing

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-multiprocessing

I have some script which use `multiprocessing` module, and Django ORM. 
Scenario is quite simple:

1. get data,
2. create n processes and assing one part of data to each process,
3. do something,
4. save into DB with Django ORM.

Well, in step 4 I have problem that Django don't save all data in DB. Function which prepare data are correct and checked, but I don't know where is problem with Django. Before processes are created, old connection is closed, so that each process can have his own connection. 
Is there some problem with Django and multiprocessing, or number of maximum connections (I use 4 process max)?

Example code: 
    connection.close()
    #part where I call function "fun", and sending data
    p = Process(target=fun, args=(i, data,)

```
def fun(i, data):
   result_1 = some_other_fun(data) #this is list
   result_2 = some_other_fun2(data) #this is model specified in models.py

   save_data(result_1, result_2)


def save_data(res1, res2):
   for row in res1:
      res1.fk_to_another_table = res2
      res1.some_info = func()
      res1.save()
```

Long story short. If I call save_data from Process, save() method doesn't save row in table. If that method is called without using Process (just normal call of script), everything is ok.

Comment: What does 'Django don't save all data in DB' exactly mean? Which data is saved and which data is not saved? Could you post some snippets of the code you're using?

Comment: Exactly what is written. I create model, populate it, and save() method dont insert that object (row) into database. All data are from the same object.

Comment: You're likely getting an error while saving the model, which is not output to the terminal because it is from another process. Execute the exact same functions without multiprocessing and see if you get any errors.

Comment: dukebody, there is no error when I call that function without mutliprocessing, in fact, it is working as it should be working.

Comment: You need to setup the django environment in each of your sub-processes.

Comment: Burkhan, it worked. I ignored that because some data were inserted so I believed that everything is ok on Django part.